# The border style is not correctly parsed by CSSStyleSheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I have a style:

```html
    <style id="style">
        .dao-tabs__nav-item--active {
            border: 1px solid var(--red);
            border-bottom-color: var(--dao-pure-white);
        }
    </style>
```

Get CSSStyleRule via js (document.getElementById('style').sheet.cssRules[0].cssText), I got cssText:

```html
    .dao-tabs__nav-item--active {
        border-top-color: ;
        border-top-style: ;
        border-top-width: ;
        border-right-color: ;
        border-right-style: ;
        border-right-width: ;
        border-bottom-style: ;
        border-bottom-width: ;
        border-left-color: ;
        border-left-style: ;
        border-left-width: ;
        border-image-source: ;
        border-image-slice: ;
        border-image-width: ;
        border-image-outset: ;
        border-image-repeat: ;
        border-bottom-color: var(--dao-pure-white);
    }
```

The border style is not correctly.

My browser, Chrome 109 and Firefox 108

I wonder why the border-color is lost.

If I don't use css variables in border,

```html
    <style>
        .dao-tabs__nav-item--active {
            border: 1px solid var(--red);
            border-bottom-color: var(--dao-pure-white);
        }
    </style>
```

I get correct result.

```html
    .dao-tabs__nav-item--active {
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-top-color: red;
        border-right-color: red;
        border-left-color: red;
        border-image: initial;
        border-bottom-color: var(--dao-pure-white);
    }
```

Comment: can you share your html code

Comment: and please show the "--dao-pure-white" definition

Comment: Then `--dao-pure-white` may be undefined. You can check by assigning a fallback value for your custom property like `border-bottom-color: var(--dao-pure-white, magenta);`...

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. In fact, the problem is not the results of the browser performance, but the results returned by JavaScript.

The lib I use relies on the parsing result of JavaScript, which leads to the loss of styles.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define and use the --dao-pure-white variable globally, you must define it in  :root{}

```css
:root{
    --dao-pure-white:#fff;
}
body{
  background:#2b2b2b;
}

.dao-tabs__nav-item--active {
  padding:10px;
    border:1px solid;
    border-bottom-color: var(--dao-pure-white);
}
```

```html
<div class="dao-tabs__nav-item--active">
Lorem ipsun
</div>
```